# Why this for loop makes the program to stop working? (C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop

friends. The next console program allows the user to enter a binary number and it outputs the decimal equivalent. It is compiled in Windows with Codeblocks without errors or warnings.
But, when running the program, you enter a binary number, press enter button and then a window pops up saying "Program stopped working correctly because of a problem" and the program is closed.
If I eliminate the for loop (which is responsible for transforming the binary number into a decimal number) and then compile and run the program, no problem appears.

Why this for loop creates this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int conversor(char a);

int main() {
    char bina[10];
    unsigned int len, n = 1, value = 0;

    cout << "\nEnter a binary integer: ";
    cin >> bina;
    len = strlen(bina);

        for(len--;len>=0;len--) {
        value = value + conversor(bina[len])*n;
        n = n * 2;
        };

    cout << value;
}

int conversor(char a) {
    if(a=='1') return 1;
    else if(a=='0') return 0;
};
```

Comment: unsigned int always >=0 so your loop condition never gets false

Comment: That's the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using unsigned int and if you have:

```
unsigned int len = 0;
len--;

cout << len << endl;
```

len will still be **positive** value.

Your program will stop because the len variable is going out of bounds.
This is something I am getting after running your program , I am printing len variable at every iteration. So , there is a very large value of len due to which it is going out of bounds for bina array.

```
Enter a binary integer: 11001
len = 4
len = 3
len = 2
len = 1
len = 0
len = 4294967295
Segmentation fault
```

Change it into signed int.
Your program will work then.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answers. It worked fine with signed int.

Comment: Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

your variable called "len" is of type "unsigned int", so it can never be less than zero and the loop never terminates.

Use a plain int instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was exactly the problem.